# Can I run Azure Cmdlets/Powershell scripts from code within an Azure Website?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

Long story short I have a Azure Powershell script (think Storage Account creation) that I want to run from within an Azure Website - is that possible at all?

If not directly from the website, can I put it in some sort of other resource that can be called?  What is the recommended way of going about this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can run PowerShell script within an Azure Web App or Web Job (or from [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)). But there are some limitations coming from the [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

If you run into a specific issue with it, feel free to ask a new question that targets that issue specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't execute a powerShell script within your Azure Website without limitations, but you can host your powershell script in an automation runbook
and execute it with an [http call](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-webhooks/) (webhook) from your Azure Website, besides another solution would be to create the storage account using
the [Azure Management API](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries).